# updating array response to mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, associative-array

I have the following query which works.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblDebits_Drafted SET RecordID = '123', ErrorDescription = 'test4' WHERE AccountID = '2222100000010717' AND DRC_TransactionID = '7'";
```

I am converting the values to variables from two different arrays. RecordID and ErrorDescription come from the response array and AccountID and DRC_Transaction come from the input array.

These are the variables and they work just fine:

```
$AccountID = $data['AccountID'];echo '<br>';
                $EffectiveDate = $data['EffectiveDate'];echo '<br>';
                $DayOfMonth = $data['DayOfMonth'];echo '<br>';
                $DebitType = $data['DebitType'];echo '<br>';
                $DebitAmount = $data['DebitAmount'];echo '<br>';
                $Memo = $data['Memo'];echo '<br>';
                $DRC_TransactionID =$data['DRC_TransactionID'];echo '<br>';

                $RecordID = $AmpResponse['AddDebitOrFeeResult']['RecordID'];echo '<br>';
                $ErrorDescription = $AmpResponse['AddDebitOrFeeResult']['ErrorDescription'];
```

Here is what I have so far for the query but it's not set right. The WHERE and the AND keywords are not active.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblDebits_Drafted SET RecordID = '".$RecordID."', ErrorDescription = '".$ErrorDescription."' WHERE AccountID = '".$AccountID."' AND DRC_TransactionID = '".$DRC_TransactionID."'";
```

Not sure how to write this so it runs correctly...
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error and when yes which one exactly?

Comment: The sql is just returning nothing at this point.

Comment: echo the sql and please use prepared statements, second use error management to see if an erro occurs

Answer (score 0):

the final solution that worked is as follows:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE tblDebits_Drafted SET RecordID = '$RecordID', ErrorDescription = '$ErrorDescription' WHERE AccountID = '$AccountID' AND DRC_TransactionID = '$DRC_TransactionID'";
```